# Installing wifi certificate

Tags: wi-fi, certificates

I want to connect my Samsung Galaxy SIII to my University's wifi network. I have the certificate on my computer. I'm trying to install it. I have transferred it to my mobile's download folder and to the root folder via Android file transfer. Only if I go under Settings>Security>Install from device storage, Downloads appears to be empty. How do I install that p12 certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty absurd to me, but while Security didn't see the certificate, Docs to go actually installed it. However, this forced me to have a pin on the lock screen, or a password, which are both very uncomfortable for me, so this opens a new question.